# Waiting many hours for the job training to start, How can I know? And will I pay this time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

My AI-Platform job is taking too many hours to start, in the logs I only see the initial messages:

> 2020-05-19T20:19:29.069Z service Validating job requirements...
>
> 2020-05-19T20:19:29.449Z service Job creation request has been
>   successfully validated
>
> 2020-05-19T20:19:29.718698960Z service Waiting for job to be
>   provisioned
>
> 2020-05-19T20:19:29.768Z service Job
>   container_seq2seq_job_20200519_201839 is queued
>
> 2020-05-19T20:19:31.354650481Z service Waiting for training program to
>   start

It looks like there are no resources or similar and the job is not running, there should be some printings from my code.

Can you help me: How can I know why is waiting? And if the billing is active? I think it is but no work is done and I will have to pay for it.

Comment: You don't have additional logs? Is  your training is large? How do you trigger the job?

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere but it finally ended, it took almost 20 hours. I got confused because it was not printing anything (but others jobs I had launched did it) so I thought it was waiting but it was actually running. So the question is now answered.

Comment: Ah ok, you have other jobs in parallel. Maximum of 25 in parallel. It was maybe the issue...

Comment: How many parallel jobs were you running @EduardoMuñozSala?